# AWS - simple notification SMS failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using the Node.js API to send SMSes to mobile numbers in India.

When I am sending an SMS to an [Bharti Airtel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharti_Airtel) number they are received by the receiver. But to the [Vodafone Idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vodafone_Idea) (Vi) number no SMS is received and it happens to many Vi numbers. But sometimes SMSes are received on the Vi number. But when the SMSes are send through the console to Vi numbers then they are received each time the SMSes are send. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Many, perhaps most, readers will not know what a VI number is ([Vodafone Idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vodafone_Idea)).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your are using [Amazon SNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Simple_Notification_Service). Here are some helpful resources:

- [Troubleshooting SMS messages sent to recipients in India](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-sms-india-troubleshooting.html)
- [How do I access Amazon SNS topic delivery logs for SMS messages?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/)
- [How do I troubleshoot mobile text message (SMS) failures in Amazon SNS?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-troubleshoot-sms-message-failures/)

Fundamentally, you need to enable and then view the [CloudWatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud#Amazon_CloudWatch) logs for your SMS messages.

Potential problems include:

- you've exceeded your monthly SMS spending quota
- you've exceeded your maximum message price
- some carriers may block SMS messages depending on content

Also, be aware of *[Special requirements for sending SMS messages to recipients in India](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-senderid-india.html)*.